C++ function template specialization based on the templated return type
In C++20, instead of doing
size_t count = 42;
std::vector<int> my_vector;
vec.reserve(count);
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(vec));

I want to be able to just say
std::vector<int> my_vector = get_from_cin<int>(42);

Problem is, I also want to have a similar facility for std::list:
std::list<int> my_list = get_from_cin<int>(42);

so I tried defining two function templates:
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> get_from_cin(size_t count) {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vec.reserve(count);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(vec));
    return vec;
}

template<typename T>
std::list<T> get_from_cin(size_t count) {
    std::list<T> list;
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(list));
    return list;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> my_vector = get_from_cin<int>(42);
}

which (expectedly) lead to ambiguity when specializing the template:
main.cpp:36:34: error: call to 'get_from_cin' is ambiguous
   36 |     std::vector<int> my_vector = get_from_cin<int>(42);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/EbdxTEcns
How can I modify the code so that this ambiguity is eliminated and the resulting code for calling the templated function is as concise as possible?
PS. I would just name the two functions differently but that feels contrary to the C++ style.

How about get_from_cin<std::vector<int>>(42);?

I don't think naming two functions differently is non-C++ish, it would be a reasonable solution (as long as you can provide nice names for the functions) Making return type a template (like above comment suggests) would work, but seems like an overkill to me. Or you could use output parameter instead - they are somewhat frowned upon, but IMHO it's justifiable for such use case.

You can probably return a dummy type and write a templated freestanding assignment operator that deduces the container type - but it seems like a ridiculous amount of work for some pretty questionable syntactic sugar

I'm not saying it's the best solution, but one approach that people have used is returning an object that has a conversion operator to vector or list.

If you can use C++23, then something like this can help:
#include <ranges>
#include <cassert>
auto vec = std::views::istream<int>(cin)
         | std::views::take(42)
         | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
assert((size(vec) == 42));

The downside is however, that if user inputs 43 numbers instead, the 43th number will be dropped for ever. Special case of counted input iterator is an unsolved problem within the realms of std. The reliable solution is still reserve followed by copy_n. I don't approve of template<template> syntax in user code, so I don't follow that route. But something like this can be useful:
template<std::ranges::range C>
    requires (not std::ranges::view<C>)
auto from_istream(std::istream& ins, std::size_t n, auto&& ...args)
    requires std::constructible_from<C, decltype(args)...>
{
    C res{std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...};

    if constexpr (
       requires  (C cnt, std::size_t sz)
       { cnt.reserve(sz); }
    )    res.reserve(n + res.size());

    std::copy_n
       ( std::istream_iterator
            < std::ranges::range_value_t<C> >(ins)
       , n, std::back_inserter(res));

    return res;//nrvo copy elision.   
};

Now you can instantiate it like this:
auto vec = from_istream<std::vector<int>>(cin,42);
assert((vec.size == 42));
auto lst = from_istream<std::list<int>>(cin,42);

In either case you need the type id of yor object on the right hand side of the assignment to instruct compiler what to create. Then type deduction and direct initialization handle the rest.

Thanks you for mentioning the views::istream | views::take problem! That's exactly the reason why I'm using iterators instead.

counted input iterator is on my nerves. I cannot stop thinking about it. If a range alternative for simple take is available, I will jump on it.

The difficulty faced by the function get_from_cin, more importantly than the technical difficulty of not being able to overload by return type, is that it's trying to do more than just "getting values from cin": it's also reading only a fixed number of values, and then additionally trying to fill a specific container with those values.
What the caller would ideally do is:
auto vec = std::views::istream<int>(std::cin)  // read ints from cin 
         | std::views::take(42)                // but only 42
         | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();     // and put them into a vector, or list, or whatever

as this way of writing the code allows one to express the logic more clearly.*
You can, of course, still put the first 2 stages of the pipeline into a function parameterized on the count of integers, if this is a pattern that is repeated often, and leave the caller to decide which container to fill up.
The above snippet does need C++23 (for the std::ranges::to), but a crude implementation can be written** like this:
template<template<typename...> typename Container>
auto To(std::ranges::input_range auto&& range) {
    Container<std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>> result;
    std::ranges::copy(range, std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

and then the call looks like:
auto vec = To<std::vector>(std::views::istream<int>(std::cin) 
                           | std::views::take(42));

* Whether this syntax is actually more readable is subjective, depending to some extent on your collaborators tastes and preferences for "good C++".
** Implementing To correctly will involve more work and accounting for edge cases, which I have entirely ignored here. Also, one would probably want to provide an appropriate operator| to let To be used in a pipeline more naturally.
Here's a demo.

You can do something similar to get the same effect: Have a single function that has two conversion operators.
struct get_from_cin_return {
  std::size_t count;
  template<typename T>
  operator std::vector<T>() && {
    // ...
  }
  template<typename T>
  operator std::list<T>() && {
    // ...
  }
};
auto get_from_cin(std::size_t count) {
  return get_from_cin_return{ count };
}

std::vector<int> i = get_from_cin(20);
std::list<double> d = get_from_cin(10);

This version also gets rid of the template parameter in get_from_cin<T>, but you can put it back in if you want to be more explicit. You could also go back to your "different functions for different types", with an even more explicit get_from_cin<std::vector<T>>/get_from_cin<std::list<T>>. That might be more cleanly written as get_from_cin(n) | std::ranges::to<vector_or_list>

This is really interesting! Is there a way to prevent storing get_from_cin_return objects in variables and passing them around? I want to store a reference to an input stream inside the struct, and as such it should not live longer than the instruction it was created in.

You cannot overload/specialize based on return value type.
Also as the accepted answer in this post explains there are advantages to avoid using template specialization when overloading is possible.
You can however overload function templates (one for vector<T> and one for list<T> etc.) based on an out parameter passed by reference:
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void get_from_cin(size_t count, std::vector<T> & vec) {
    vec.reserve(count);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(vec));
}

template<typename T>
void get_from_cin(size_t count, std::list<T> & list) {
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(list));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> my_vector;
    get_from_cin(42, my_vector);
    std::list<int> my_list;
    get_from_cin(42, my_list);
}

Live demo

You can make a single function template and use constexpr if and pass a template template argument as shown below:
template<template<typename...>typename C, typename T>
auto get_from_cin(size_t count) {
    C<T> vec;
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::vector<T>, C<T>>)
    { 
        vec.reserve(count);   
    }
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(vec));
    return vec;     
}
int main() {
    auto my_vector = get_from_cin<std::vector, int>(15);
    auto my_list = get_from_cin<std::list, int>(15);   
}

Working demo

You can get exactly the syntax you want by using a proxy:
struct GetFromCinProxy
{
    std::size_t count;

    GetFromCinProxy(std::size_t count)
        : count{count}
    {}

    template <class T>
    operator std::vector<T>() const
    {
        std::vector<T> vec;
        vec.reserve(count);
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(vec));
        return vec;
    }

    template <class T>
    operator std::list<T>() const
    {
        std::list<T> list;
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(list));
        return list;
    }
};

GetFromCinProxy get_from_cin(std::size_t count)
{
    return {count};
};

Usage is exactly as you want:
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = get_from_cin(24);
    std::list<int> l = get_from_cin(24);
}

There are however some drawbacks, the biggest of which would be the unexpected behavior when used with deduced type:
auto x = get_from_cin(24);

The users might expect to get an iteratable container in x. Also the input doesn't get consumed here which might be counter intuitive enough to cause bugs.
